# Hibernate execute OneToMany if condition satisfied

Tags: java, hibernate, annotations, conditional-statements, one-to-many

I was wondering if it exist a way to tell to Hibernate to execute the query behind a @OneToMany only if a condition is satisfied.
This could be a very simple example:

```
@Entity
public class MyEntity {
  ...
  private Long id;
  private boolean condition;
  private List<AnotherEntity> anotherEntity;

  @Id
  @Column(name = "ID", nullable = false)
  @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
  public Long getId() {
    return id;
  }
  public void setId(Long id) {
    this.id = id;
  }

  @Basic
  @Column(name = "CONDITION")
  public Boolean getCondition() {
    return isContentChanged;
  }
  public void setIsContentChanged(Boolean condition) {
    this.condition = condition;
  }

  @OneToMany(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
  @JoinColumn(name = "SECOND_ID")
  **@Conditional(clause = "CONDITION = true")**
  public List<AnotherEntity> getAnotherEntity() {
    return anotherEntity;
  }
  public void setAnotherEntity(List<AnotherEntity> anotherEntity) {
    this.anotherEntity = anotherEntity;
  }
}

@Entity
public class AnotherEntity {
   private id
   private secondId
   ...
}
```

So what I would like is:
- if the condition in the annotation @Conditional is satisfied, Hibernate execute the query related to the @OneToMany annotation
- if the condition in the annotation @Conditional is not satisfied, Hibernate do nothing with the @OneToMany annotation

I do not know if that already exist somewhere in Hibernate. Otherwise could be a great new feature.

Answer (score 1):

One way you may be able to solve this depending on the context of `AnotherEntity` would be to use a Hibernate Filter.  I have used something similar in the past where we had a `OneToMany` of a specific entity type but only certain values were to be returned based on user access.

Other ways may include using a `@Formula` or `@Where` annotation.

All three of these options are available in the documentation for Hibernate 5.2, starting [here](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/5.2/userguide/html_single/Hibernate_User_Guide.html#mapping-column-formula).

*Update*:

What I am about to explain only applies to associations which are explicitly defined as `LAZY` fetch types.  If you keep the default `EAGER` fetch type or explicitly set it to `EAGER`, the following does not apply.

Given that your association is using `LAZY` fetch types, you could bake the condition as a part of your data access layer queries at runtime.  There isn't an annotation to this so it would be part of your code but it at least allows you to minimize the join at runtime.

For situations where your condition is *true*, you either specify that the collection should be loaded `EAGER` if using the deprecated Hibernate Criteria API or you'll want to use a `JOIN/JOIN FETCH` if using the JPA Criteria API.  Note that `JOIN` will only allow you to apply predicates again the collection to filter the root entities; however `JOIN FETCH` will also populate the collection for you.

This won't allow you to *filter* the collection results but it at least provides you a means to eliminate the join while allowing the join to be part of the query at runtime based on some condition.

This is very analygous where a search form has 10 searchable fields; however you only apply the appropriate predicates to a base query if a given field has a value; however no predicate and perhaps no specific joins are added to the base query if a value is not provided to improve runtime query performance.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. However it is not what I am looking for. The '@Filter', '@Where' annotations are filtering the result (it add a where clause to the sql statement). The '@Formula' is a way to do calculation on the DB side. What I am looking for is a way to indicate to HIbernate to do the join or not. If the condition attribute in MyEntity is true do the join otherwise do nothing.

Comment: It would be helpful to know why you want to achieve this kind of specific behavior, because maybe there is an other way to solve your problem.

Comment: For the majority of the "MyEntity" there is no "AnotherEntity" relation. So what I would like to avoid is Hibernate querying the database for nothing. Cause even if the query took only 1 ms to be executed if "MyEntity" table contain a million row the time spend querying for nothing is enormous.